# Coding Minecraft plugin (Jar)

Tags: plugins, jar, minecraft

I'm a newbie and I wanted to create a new plugin for my Minecraft server (a .jar file).
It has to make a whole tree (all the wood connected) fall breaking only one block.
I want it to be turned on or off using a specific in-game command.
Do you have any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by looking at how to make a "hello world" plugin.
Find a tutorial online (there are many), for how to setup a basic plugin.

Once you have done that, have a look at this to setup an event listener.
https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Event_API_Reference

Then, use this event instead of the example one
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockBreakEvent.html

Lastly, loop through all the surrounding blocks and check if they are wood logs, if so: break them.

NOTE: This is not very detailed, this is more of a guidance for you to know what to lookup. Search around internet for how to do certain things. It will take time but stick to it. And feel free to ask questions when you are really stuck :)